# Simple_HTML_DOM parse 'find' value to Integer

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm studying Simple_HTML_DOM and I found a problem where I'm working on from 2 hours without finding a solution :-(

I've the following code:

```
$num = $html->find('span.pageNum');
```

This code get number of pages on my blog and it works. GREAT.

If I do

```
echo $num[0];
```

I see the number of pages on screen, but if I try to do something like:

```
echo ($num[0]+2);
```

for example, It doesen't work like an INTEGER and it return me the following output:

```
3
```

So, I need to make the "find" to an integer and work for math operations but I tried everything and nothing works (like cast with `(int)$num[0]` and much more).

Can anyone please help me? I don't know what to do more...I really tried everything!! :-(

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does it show you when you do `echo ($num[0]+2);`?

Comment: IT's very likely $num[0] has the value of 1...check on that one first.

Comment: Thanks guys! So, yes $num[0] its like have value of 1, but if I do echo $num[0]; it show the right number of pages (127 and not 1) but If I try to do math operations, it got counted like "1"...I really don't understand why..Any suggestions?

Comment: For Eva Ojack: It show 3...

Comment: $num = $html->find('span.pageNum');
$myfile = fopen("txt/file.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $num[0]);  and on OUTPUT TXT I see: <span class="pageNum">127</span>

Comment: That sounds like your value has been converted to a string value somehow, so accessing `[0]` of that value will only give you the first character, which for `127` would be the `1` …

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE SOLUTION!!
I used:

```
$pgnum = filter_var($num[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

worked GREAT!! Thanks :-)